# UITableView Section with Index

Tags: ios, uitableview

Anything I missed in the following code? I can create a list but the list is array x26 times (26x section) in the `UITableView`. A list shown, but the section title is only point to 'A'

[image]

`arr_indexpeople` > An array of A,B,C,D,E.....Z

`arr_completeArray` > An array of a list of people

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasource method will get called for every section to load, so give the dynamic index of a section as input variable for arr_indexpeople as shown below.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [arr_indexpeople objectAtIndex:section]
}
```

Comment: thanks...but the all my items are in the array that put into Section 'A', how can I split them into A,B,C,D,E ... Z?

Comment: Yes, there is one more mistake in your code, total section count is going wrong. SectionIndexTitlesForTable get call after NumberOfSectionInTableView call. This you can find basic flow of Tableview delegates and datasource methods documentation. Initialize and fill the data in arr_indexpeople outside of delegate or datasource methods and then call the tableview. It will work.

Answer (score 4):

return [arr_indexpeople objectAtIndex:section]

Comment: thanks...but the all my items are in the array that put into Section 'A', how can I split them into A,B,C,D,E ... Z?

Answer (score 3):

You are returning objectAtIndex 0 in titleForHeaderInSection. Change it to-

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return [arr_indexpeople objectAtIndex:section]
}
```

Comment: thanks...but the all my items are in the array that put into Section 'A', how can I split them into A,B,C,D,E ... Z?

Comment: You need to filter array(arr_completeArray) using predicate & display in respective section. Read "Using Predicates with Arrays" section from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-CJBDBHCB